# Destroying Boost Asio socket without closing native handler

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, boost-asio

I am facing the following issue. I am trying to use a third party library with boost Asio and I need to inject some of the socket descriptors used by the library in io_service event loop.

The approach I use is creating a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket passing the native handler my library provides.

Problem is that library would just communicate it is not interested in a particular socket notifications (which means that library may close the socket or reuse it at a later point). In any case, I would like to do a clean up of boost sockets and destroy them, but without closing the native handler (i.e. file descriptor).

In short, is there any way of destroying a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket without closing the underlying handler? I am aware of using posix::stream_descriptor instead, but I would like my solution to be portable.

Comment: Did you try to [assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/assign.html) a dumb socket, even if it fails may be previous will be no more available...

Comment: @JeanDavy `socket.assign(protocol, native)` has a pre-condition that `socket` is not open (see the [SocketService](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SocketService.html)).  If this precondition is not met, then the state of `socket` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There is no way to destroy `ip::tcp::socket` without closing the native handler.  This cannot be portable implemented, and therefore Asio does not support it.  In particular, prior to Windows 8.1, once a socket is associated with an I/O completion port, the socket can only be disassociated by closing it<sup>1</sup>.  See [this](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/70) related github issue where Chris Kohlhoff responds to this feature request:

> This is not supported because it cannot be portably implemented. Specifically, on Windows a socket is associated to an I/O completion port and cannot be disassociated.
>
> If you are only targeting POSIX-based systems then perhaps you can stick the descriptor into a `posix::stream_descriptor` instead? This class does provide a `release()` member function.

---

<sub>1. Windows 8.1 enabled removing the completion port association via [`FileReplaceCompletionInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff728840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#FILEREPLACECOMPLETIONINFORMATION) without closing the socket.</sub>

Comment: Is it possible to use `NtSetInformationFile` in regular windows application? Is this reserved for drivers?

Answer (score 0):

> but I would like my solution to be portable

The moment you touch the native handle, the program is no longer portable.

However, once you've come to terms with that, you can call `dup()` [unix] or `DuplicateHandle()` [windows] on the native handle.

Comment: Actually I don't intend to touch the native handle, Asio and the other library are both using the same kind of native handles both in windows and unix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to swtich to **posix::stream_descriptor** and use its [release](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__basic_stream_descriptor/release.html) method.